# How do I calculate the sum from my functions?

Tags: haskell

I have a file (points.txt) with some Cartesian coordinates defined:

```
A 1.0 2.2
B 2.1 3.0
C 3.5 4.0
D 4.0 5.0
```

I have a second file (routes.txt) with routes defined based on the points from points.txt.

```
route1 ACDB
route2 ABC
```

I need to find the length of each route. So far I have a calculation of the distance between two points, like this:

```
type Point = (String, Float, Float)

distance_points :: IO ()
distance_points = do s <- readFile "pontos.txt"
                      putStr "Fom: "
                      p1 <- getLine
                      putStr "To: "
                      p2 <- getLine
                      print ( distance (search_point p1 (map words (lines s))) (search_point p2 (map words (lines s))))

search_point :: String -> [[String]] -> Point
search_point pt ([p,c1,c2]:xs) = if pt == p then (p, read(c1)::Float, read(c2)::Float)
                                             else search_point pt xs

distance :: Point -> Point -> Float
distance (s1,x1,y1) (s2,x2,y2) = sqrt ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

How can I calculate the full distance of a route?

Also, if I have several routes how can I find the longest one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of walking the file to do the calculation, write a function that takes a collection of points and does the calculation. You should _completely_ separate the code that reads the file and generates the collection of points. You could use (lookup)[http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:lookup] or full-blown (Data.Map)[http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html]

Comment: @KarolyHorvath let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31495/discussion-between-andrewc-and-karoly-horvath)

Comment: Hi AndrewC, thank you for your time. 

Unfortunately, and because I'm a really newbie on haskell, I don't have the knowledge to implement the functions you mentioned on you answer. 

That said, I also have code to load routes from routes.txt file that returns a string like "ABCD". My question is, how can I take that string and the "distance" function to make the calculation:
A to B + B to C + C to D

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm just trying to get some help with this code and believe me or not, I've spent almost a day to write the code posted on the question. If I ofended you or anyone in anyway on this site I can just remove the topic.

Comment: @pvl Don't worry. Perhaps Karoly had a particularly mean Maths teacher that was rude to him when he found stuff hard and refused to help him, and he somehow feels now that it's the best response to a student. Don't delete your questions unnecessarily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Step 1: Separate pure and non-pure code, by not writing IO till the end.

The easiest way to do this is to solve your problem in pure code first, then add the file-reading afterwards. Otherwise you'll be tempted to write a lot of IO code.

It'll be easier if you separate the name from the coordinates:

```
type Coordinates = (Float,Float)
type Name = Char -- You had String, which is also fine
type Point = (Name, Coordinates)
type Points = [Point] -- or Map String Point from Data.Map
```

Then have some practice data:

```
sampleData :: Points
sampleData = [('A',(1.0,2.2), .....
```

### Step 2: Write a function that takes a collection of points and a pair of point names and returns a distance

First you'll need a function that takes a name and gives you some coordinates.

```
coordinates :: Points -> Name -> Coordinates
```

If we're using `[Point]`, the easiest way to do this is to use `lookup`. (You can find out about functions on hoogle [like this](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=lookup) or by type [like this](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5b%28a%2C+b%29%5d+-%3E+Maybe+b), although there's no obvious way for you to know that you wanted a `Maybe`, and when you just search for `[(a,b)] -> b`, lookup is a long way down.)

Comment if you need help with this step.

Using that you'll be able to write

```
distBetween :: Points -> Name -> Name -> Float
```

### Step 3: Turn a list of names representing a path into a list of pairs of point names

```
getPath :: String -> [(Name,Name)]
```

or (cooler) use `zipWith` to get to the distances. After that, applying `sum` should be easy to finish the problem.

The cool way of making this list of pairs is to use a trick we use for the fibonacci numbers (`fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`) of zipping a function with its tail. If you've not met it, [zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azip) works like this:

```
 ghci> zip [1..5] "Hello Mum"
[(1,'H'),(2,'e'),(3,'l'),(4,'l'),(5,'o')]
zip "Hello" "ello"
[('H','e'),('e','l'),('l','l'),('l','o')]
*Main> zip "Hello" (tail "Hello")
[('H','e'),('e','l'),('l','l'),('l','o')]
```

Awesome - that's exactly the trick you need.

### Step 4: Lastly, write the code reading files to the data types you need

You'll need functions like

```
readPointsFile :: FilePath -> IO Points
readPointsFile fileName = do
    ....
    ....
    return (map readPoint pointStrings)
```

and then you can glue it together with, for example:

```
pathLengthFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO Float
pathLengthFile pointsFilename pathFilename = do
     points <- readPointsFile pointsFilename
     path <- readPathFile pathFilename
     return (getPathLength points path)
```

Notice how hardly any of the logic is in this bit. You do all the real graft in pure code.

---

Secretly I'm a massive `Applicative` fan, and want to `import Control.Applicative` and write this as

```
pathLengthFile pointsFile pathFile = 
    getPathLength <$> readPointsFile pointsFile <*> readPathFile pathFile
```

But that's another lesson for a later day. :)

Comment: Once again, thank you AndrewC. I will rethink the problem following your tips.

Comment: @pvl Updated. I find it's useful when programming in Haskell to write the types of my functions first. I can change later, but often once you've decided the types it's much easier to write the functions, because you've given yourself a specification to work to and it's more obvious what you need to do. Feel free to ask me to expand a section.

Comment: It will take me some time to understand and apply the concepts listed here. But I think that this puts me on the right track and so I'm accepting this answer.
Thank you very much AndewC.